# Getters can set private variables

Tags: javascript, oop

I think I've misunderstood something about OOP in JavaScript. As I understand it, the point of setting up a private variable with its own getter and setter functions is to protect it from accidental alteration elsewhere in the program. But I'm finding it very easy to accidentally change private variables using their getter functions, which means I must be doing something wrong.

```
function Phone(os) {
  this.os = os;
  var _phoneBook = []; // phoneBook is intended to be private
  this.newNumber = function(phoneNumber) { // set new number
    _phoneBook.push(phoneNumber);
  }
  this.listNumbers = function() { // get all numbers
    return _phoneBook;
  }
}

var andy = new Phone("Android");
andy.newNumber("555-123-4567");
console.log(andy.listNumbers()); // => ["555-123-4567"]
// You shouldn't be able to set a private property through a getter function, but you can.
var extendedPhoneBook = andy.listNumbers().push("123-456-7890"); 
console.log(andy.listNumbers()); // => ["555-123-4567", "123-456-7890"]
```

Comment: Well, objects (and hence arrays) are mutable. If you expose an object or array, it can be changed. You could return a *copy* instead, but that won't help either if the array contains more objects. Creating a deep copy seems impractical. In your case, a shallow copy seems to suffice if you really deem it necessary.

Comment: No one can exchange your `_phonebook` with a different array, but if you don't return copies of your array then everyone can change its entries.

Comment: (You have the same "problem" in any other language that passes objects as references, e.g. Java)

Comment: That helps. Is the solution, then, "your getter functions should always include code to return a copy of the variable instead of the original", or is there a larger pattern I'm missing? I ask because I've been reading up about object-oriented programming in JavaScript and none of my sources seem to mention this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Array is being passed as a reference, so when calling `listNumbers()`  you are returning the Actual Array to the exterior. You can return copies of the Array with something like this:

```
function Phone(os) {
  this.os = os;
  var _phoneBook = []; // phoneBook is intended to be private
  this.newNumber = function(phoneNumber) { // set new number
    _phoneBook.push(phoneNumber);
  }
  this.listNumbers = function() { // get all numbers
    return _phoneBook.slice(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might consider changing function `listNumbers` to something like `enumerateNumbers` that takes a function that gets passed a string for each number in your list to hide the internal array, something like this:

```
function Phone(os) {
  this.os = os;
  var _phoneBook = []; // phoneBook is intended to be private
  this.newNumber = function(phoneNumber) { // set new number
    _phoneBook.push(phoneNumber);
  }
  this.enumerateNumbers = function(cb) { // get all numbers
    for (var idx in _phoneBook) {
      cb(_phoneBook[idx]);
    }
  }
}

var andy = new Phone("Android");
andy.newNumber("555-123-4567");

andy.enumerateNumbers(function(num) { console.log(num); })
```